# Occasional error when running sp_BlitzFirst

Tags: sp-blitzfirst, sp-blitzcache

I have set up sp_BlitzFirst to run as a job (for the PowerBI Dashboard). Occasionally, when it runs, it gets the following error:

```
Msg 8152, Sev 16, State 13, Line 2980 : String or binary data would be truncated. [SQLSTATE 22001]
```

This is actually happening in the sp_BlitzCache procedure at this line:

```
INSERT #stored_proc_info ( SPID, SqlHandle, QueryHash, variable_name, variable_datatype, compile_time_value, proc_name )
SELECT vi.SPID, vi.SqlHandle, vi.QueryHash, vi.variable_name, vi.variable_datatype, vi.compile_time_value, vi.proc_name
FROM #variable_info AS vi
OPTION ( RECOMPILE );
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks.

Darrell

Comment: We're doing support over in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit), so I'm gonna vote to close this. That's where you'd wanna go to open issues. There's [already a fix](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_BlitzCache.sql) for this particular one in the dev branch. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because We're doing support on [GitHub](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit).

Answer (score 0):

You'll get that error when one of the columns in the select won't fit into the destination table.

Tracking it down can take some time, but it's just like kindergaten - try and fit the shapes in the holes.

If you compare #Variable_info to #stored_proc_info, you will probably find that one of the columns in #variable_info is larger than its corresponding column in #stored_proc_info.

I can't find #variable_info in my version of the sp_blitzcache, so I can't tell which columns don't match.

Often, I track it down by running a query like this:

```
SELECT len(vi.SPID) as spid, len(vi.SqlHandle) as handle, len(vi.QueryHash as hash), len(vi.variable_name) as variable_name, 
len(vi.variable_datatype) as data_type, len(vi.compile_time_value) as compile_time, len(vi.proc_name) as proc_name
FROM #variable_info AS vi;
```

and looking for values that are too big.